# Abrir un Archivo de Excel en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Quiero abrir un archivo de Excel al pulsar un botón; el archivo está en una carpeta compartida de un servidor.

Cuando estoy programando en mi `localhost` , si funciona con este código:

```
protected void BtnChk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{            
    Process.Start(@"\\server\vol1\Files\Book1.xls");
}
```

De esa manera doy clic y busca la ruta, y el archivo de excel inicia automáticamente.

Sin embargo, cuando la aplicación web la subo al servidor asignado host y todo, no me trae nada.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione, o que otra manera podría hacerlo?
Este código es para verificar si existe el archivo, y si me funciona!! no entiendo porque visualizarlo no

```
            if (File.Exists(@"\\server\Files\Book1.xls"))
       {
            ButCrear.Visible = false;
            BtnChk.Visible = true;`

        }
```

Comment: CarlosR93, podrías darle permisos de lectura al usuario "IIS_USRS", ¿Te genera algún error?. Encierra tu código en un bloque `try/catch` y captura el error que pueda tener. actualiza tu pregunta con los resultados. Comprueba si el archivo además existe y no está abierto _(Excel solo puede tener abierta un archivo con el mismo nombre)_.

Comment: okey, otra cosa, había puesto el archivo en el servidor, y puse la ruta como si fura de local C: , pero al momento de hacer eso me aparecía `Access denied`

Comment: Carlos, entonces ese es el error, debes darle permiso al usuario `IIS_USRS` para que pueda leer ese archivo; sin embargo, no se si es la mejor práctica.

Comment: la cuestión es: como le doy permiso, por ejemplo en el `Proccess.Start();` como puedo poner las credenciales?

Comment: ¿Donde esperas que abra el archivo Excel? ¿Del lado del servidor, o del lado del cliente?  Porque obviamente, si tratas de hacer un `Process.Start` en el servidor, este tratará de abrir el archivo en el servidor, y el cliente no verá nada. Y obviamente, cuando trabajabas localmente, esto no era un problema, porque el cliente y el servidor eran la misma máquina.

Comment: Okey, ya entiendo sstan, ¿como puedo abrir el archivo que esta en servidor, en mi Excel de la maquina ?, como dije, poner la credenciales para accesar al servidor, y que el archivo de excel lo "Extrae" y lo pueda ver en mi app de Excel(local), asi cuando le doy guardar el archivo de excel se modifica y se guarda directamente en la carpeta del servidor, manipular archivos de excel a través de la aplicación web...

Comment: @CarlosR93, en tu pregunta no es claro para qué necesitas abrir el archivo Excel en una máquina diferente, ¿considerarías en su lugar, descargar el archivo Excel?

Comment: loa que quiero es evitar que el usuario descarge el archivo de Excel, modificarlo , y luego volverlo a subir; si no que simplemente lo puedan ver, modificar y guardarlo, esta ubicado en una carpeta compartida de un servidor

Comment: @CarlosR93, si tienen la posibilidad a usar un [control de tercero](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSpreadsheetDemos/Default.aspx). =)

Answer (score 1):

Para darle permiso a la carpeta en donde tienes el archivo Excel a consultar, sigue estos pasos:

1. Selecciona la carpeta destino: Ejemplo: *C:/miCarpeta*.
2. Presiona click derecho > Propiedades.
3. Ve a la pestaña *Seguridad* y presiona el Botón *Editar*.
4. Aparecerá una nueva ventana. Selecciona el usuario *IIS_USRS* y debajo aparecerá un cuadro con los **"Permisos de IIS_USRS"**.
5. Selecciona el check en la columna "*Allow/Permitir*" al permiso de lectura "*Read*".
6. Presiona el botón "*Aplicar*" y luego el botón "*Aceptar*" para guardar los cambios.

Intenta de nuevo acceder a tu archivo.

> **NOTA:** Puedes darle permisos especiales o "Full Control", pero no creo que sea lo mas recomendable.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero ya tengo  estos permisos activados...

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que leyeras un poco de [Cliente Servidor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc450447(v=vs.71).aspx) ya que si deseas subir tu código a un server obviamente el proceso que va a correr es el excel de donde este alojada tu aplicación Web.

Ahora si lo que quieres es que se habrá el Excel del cliente, entonces debes usar ActiveX, y lamento decirte que solo funciona en IE (no lo sé si en otros), y el Script de Java Script Seria el siguiente.

```
function test() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
  }
```

Donde teste.xlsx es la dirección del archivo (del lado del servidor). Ejemplo.
Tu carpeta donde esta tu pagina web:

http://site.com/views/pagina.html

Tu archivo xlsx esta en la siguiente dirección:

http://site.com/views/upload/teste.xlsx

entonces el path seria asi:

```
function test() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("/upload/teste.xlsx");
  }
```

Saludos.

Comment: No amigo, el ActiveXObject ya no funciona... Creo que mejor pondré la opción de descargar el archivo y que lo vuelvan a subir...

Comment: Yo creo que si amigo. `Sharepoint` Lo utiliza, con el puedes abrir archivos de `excel`, `word`, `paint`, `publisher`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

es debido a que utilizas la dirección del localhost para obtener la ruta del servidor desde donde se ejecuta la pagina utiliza System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable y te mostrara la carpeta en la que se encuentra espero te sirva